# Masoretic v Septuagint

Tags: tanach, translation, septuagint

Having come across some claims, and some websites, there seems to be a disagreement between the Masoretic and Septuagint scrolls/texts and that one is more or less reliable than the other.

**Are there any outside sources that can attest to these claims, and which one (if not both) is truly reliable?**

Here are some examples I found in this [website](https://sites.google.com/site/errorsinthebible/examining-the-septuagint-and-the-masoretic-text) of the "differences":

(It seems that this specific website holds the view that the Septuagint is accurate and was "modified" by Rabbis to "debunk" the christian claims)

> Exodus 1: The number 75 replaced by 70
>
> Genesis 10:24 some generations removed.
>
> Deuteronomy 32:8 “Angels Of Elohim” replaced with “children of
> Israel.”
>
> Jeremiah 10 verses 6 and 7 have been added in the Masoretic.
>
> Psalm 96:10 “Say among the nations, YHWH reigns from the wood”
> omitted.
>
> Isaiah 19:18 “city of righteousness” changed to the “city of the sun”
> or in some versions “the city of destruction.”

Comment: Actually the Masoretes did that job. Those times many slightly different manuscripts were available, and they meticulously selected the version based on our tradition.

Comment: In order to have an outside source credibly  testifying for either side  it would have to be older and more reliable than  both sides. You are looking for something impossible.

Comment: Note that the original Septuagint was only the Torah. The Navi was much later and is basically Christian. As far as I remember, the Septuagint that we have nowadays even for the Torah is not the original translation of the seventy.

Answer (score 2):

Both textual traditions (along with the [Samaritan Pentateuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritan_Pentateuch), which has similarities with each) predate Christianity by centuries. Basically, [texts, whether religious, or otherwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism), present a rainbow-like distribution in terms of variation.

To illustrate this by way of a basic example, for the purpose of clarification:

- The [difference in genealogies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogies_of_Genesis):

  - The [Masoretic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text), owing to its [Babylonian influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity), points to [the time when the first city-states appeared in the Levant, about 4,000 BCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_of_the_ancient_Near_East); thus, [Ur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur), Abraham's birthplace, was founded around 3,800 BCE, which is about the same time as the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch) of the [Hebrew calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) of 3,761 BCE.
  - The [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint), on the other hand, owing to its [Egyptian influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_Kingdom), points to [the time when the first humans settlements appeared in the region, around 6,000 BCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_Egypt#Lower_Egypt); more to the point, its chronology starts five millennia before the [Seleucid era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_era) or 311/2 BCE.

Personally, I would shy away from [conspiracy theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conspiracy_theory).